# Is there a way to create a single PDF from one workbook and add a single tab from another one into it?

Tags: excel, vba

Basically, I was wondering if is possible to create a single PDF from 2 different workbooks sheets. I know how to write a code to create a PDF using multiple worksheets from one workbook, but I was wondering if into this PDF can be added one worksheet from another workbook at the end using VBA?

```
Sub SaveAllToPDF()

Dim OriginalSheet
Dim i As Long

OriginalSheet = ActiveSheet.Name


    Sheets(Array(sheets)).Select
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        "C:\Users\xhdhfd\Documents\PDF\" & Sheets("Admin").Range("H25").Value & ".pdf"

Sheets(OriginalSheet).Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Copy both sheets into a new sheet and then save as PDF.

Comment: First workbook has 23 sheets and the second one has a sheet with multiple graphs, therefore I cannot do that @BigBen

Comment: Create a new temporary workbook and merge the sheets in it. Then discard the temp workbook, i.e. don't save it.

Comment: And how can I do that if the files are in different folders?

Comment: Open both files and copy the sheets you want to a new workbook (?).